# rsync using keygen login in bash script

Tags: ssh, bash, rsync

So I have set up a password-less ssh login for a server. I can run rsync from the command line, and it works beautifully, and doesn't ask me for a password:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh myDir user@X.X.X.X:/place/myDir
```

However, when I put this in a bash script and execute the script, it stops to ask me for a password.

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -avz -e ssh myDir user@X.X.X.X:/place/myDir
```

Why is this happening? What should I look for to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add the path to your identity file like this:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa" myDir user@X.X.X.X:/place/myDir
```

Comment: Wont work if your ssh key has a passphrase (which it should).

Comment: Yes, you are right, but according to what the MirroredFate says it is passwordless.

Comment: This works, and solves my problem. If I should be using something like `ssh-agent` with a passphrase, that is a different problem I will need to address.

Comment: SSH password != SSH key passphrase

Answer (score 1):

You need to source your ssh agent. I use keychain for this.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-keyc2/

Answer (score 0):

I like to set up ssh configurations in a configuration file - ~/.ssh/config

It looks like this

```
Host xxx-master
HostName X.X.X.X
User user
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/xxx_id_rsa
ControlMaster yes
ControlPath ~/.ssh/xxx_ctrl_path

Host xxx
HostName X.X.X.X
User user
ControlPath ~/.ssh/xxx_ctrl_path
```

Then I `ssh xxx-master` and it asks me for the passphrase.  While I continue to be logged into xxx-master, I can `ssh xxx` without a passphrase.

Is this better than ssh agent? I don't know.  I use this method because I have not figured out ssh-agent.